# Add a circle between two vertical div in HTML

Tags: html, css

How can I add a circle on top of two vertical div in HTML? I succeed in having 2 vertical boxes:
[image]

but I cannot figure out how to have a circle in the middle like the following:

[image]

The goal is to have a white circle with a blue line and being able to add a logo in the circle.  I have the following code snippet:

http://jsfiddle.net/wL9xoad3/

```css
.html {
  height: 100%;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body {
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

.vidyard_padding {
  height: 100%;
}

.vc {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.vc-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.cta {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;
}

.cta-full {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.cta-half {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

.cta-block {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.cta-block-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.cta-block p {
  line-height: 1.4125;
  margin: 0;
}

.cta-block p.white {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.cta-block p+.btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.cta-block .btn {
  background-color: #414142;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cta-block .btn:hover {
  background-color: #313132;
}
```

```html
<div class="cta-half">
  <div class="cta-block" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
    <div class="cta-block-inner">
      <p class="black">Watch our Quick Start</p>
      <a class="btn" href="https://google.com">Quick Start</a> </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="cta-half">
  <div class="cta-block" style="background-color:#47b2ffff;">
    <div class="cta-block-inner">
      <p class="white">Start in the Cloud</p>
      <a class="btn" href="https://google.com">Cloud</a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `::before` or an `::after` pseudo element with an empty `content` and some positioning. You can set the `width` and `height` of the new element and add some `border-radius` to make it a circle. Don't forget to set `position: relative` on the `.cta-half` element so you can move the circle relative to this.

You can add the following to your snippet on jsfiddle, it should work:

```css
.cta-half {
  position: relative;
}

.cta-half:last-of-type::after {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #47b2ff;
  content: '';
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50px;
}
```

If you want to add a logo in the circle, you can update your `content` and add a `url()`. I'd probably grab the [svg version of the logo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Google_SVG_logos#/media/File:Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg) and encode it using [this tool](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/). It will convert the image and use it like this:

```css
content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%0A%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 533.5 544.3' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M533.5 278.4c0-18.5-1.5-37.1-4.7-55.3H272.1v104.8h147c-6.1 33.8-25.7 63.7-54.4 82.7v68h87.7c51.5-47.4 81.1-117.4 81.1-200.2z' fill='%234285f4'/%3E%3Cpath d='M272.1 544.3c73.4 0 135.3-24.1 180.4-65.7l-87.7-68c-24.4 16.6-55.9 26-92.6 26-71 0-131.2-47.9-152.8-112.3H28.9v70.1c46.2 91.9 140.3 149.9 243.2 149.9z' fill='%2334a853'/%3E%3Cpath d='M119.3 324.3c-11.4-33.8-11.4-70.4 0-104.2V150H28.9c-38.6 76.9-38.6 167.5 0 244.4l90.4-70.1z' fill='%23fbbc04'/%3E%3Cpath d='M272.1 107.7c38.8-.6 76.3 14 104.4 40.8l77.7-77.7C405 24.6 339.7-.8 272.1 0 169.2 0 75.1 58 28.9 150l90.4 70.1c21.5-64.5 81.8-112.4 152.8-112.4z' fill='%23ea4335'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
```

You can also add some `padding` to make the logo smaller.

Result:

[image]

Comment: I tried the above; A circle is indeed displayed but now the two square blocks are positioned horizontally and not vertically.

Comment: I define this: 

.cta-half {
    float: left; 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
}

And it fixed the issue

Comment: Also my last pain point is with regard to the image. I have an hard time adding the image to the circle. I tried: 

`.cta-half:last-of-type::after {
  background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/753px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png");
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #47b2ff;
  content: '';
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50px;
}
` But the image is not displayed at hall.

Comment: I've just updated my answer with details on the logo.